# How to execute huge sql native code using hibernate?

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

I need to create a web application that allows users to create a database using ER diagrams and then perform basic CRUD operations on it. I have already done most of the job, how it's work:
[image]

As you can see after create tables i have ready to use SQL code (right bottom corner).
**And now i need to execute this code from java.**
I am using *Java (1.8)*, *Oracle(11gR2)*, *Hibernate (5.4.9.Final)*
Here is my code which is used to execute native queries (i am loading sql from file):

```
Session session = hibernateFactory.openSession();

String query = null;
try {
    query = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(ClassLoader.getSystemResource("test.sql").toURI())));
} catch (IOException | URISyntaxException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
String finalQuery = query;
session.doWork(connection -> connection.prepareStatement(finalQuery).execute());
```

And here is the question:
Is this possible to execute this whole code at once?
I can execute this:
[image]

but when i will put another table, then i will got this error:
[image]

Its seems like hibernate don't like character: ";"

**Is it possible to fix this and force this prepareStatement to execute whole code sql? Or i will need to do it in parts?**

Comment: Oracle's JDBC driver may only allow one statement to be executed at a time.  That aside, why are you trying to execute `CREATE TABLE` statements at all?  Hibernate is supposed to be managing this for the most part.

Comment: A PreparedStatement is intended to execute one SQL statement. I can imagine that multiple statements are already not allowed because that smells like SQL injection.

Comment: Ahh so it isn't possible :( 

thanks guys.

Comment: Tim Biegeleisen, like i said before i need to create database from java, that is why i need to execute "create table"

Comment: You can run `create table` through JDBC, but you have to run each statement individually. But using a tool like Liquibase or Flyway is usually the better approach to manage your schema migrations. Why re-invent such a thing?